# Cannot extract a file path from a package URI error in Flutter but I'm not using URI package

Tags: android-studio, dart, flutter

i have just update my Mac to Mojave with a Clean installation, so I re-installed all my apps including Android Studio and Flutter, as the first time, i followed the Flutter installation guide. I got this error at re-opening an previous project, but if i create a new Flutter project I don't have problems, I tried to remake all project copying the code but I got the same errors:

```
Unhandled exception:
Unsupported operation: Cannot extract a file path from a package URI
#0      _SimpleUri.toFilePath (dart:core/uri.dart:4589:7)
#1      _writeDepfile (package:vm/frontend_server.dart:662:32)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      FrontendCompiler.compile (package:vm/frontend_server.dart:367:15)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      _FlutterFrontendCompiler.compile (package:frontend_server/server.dart:31:22)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      starter (package:frontend_server/server.dart:133:27)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      main (file:///b/build/slave/Mac_Engine/build/src/flutter/frontend_server/bin/starter.dart:8:30)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      _startIsolate.<anonymous closure> (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:287:32)
#7      _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage
(dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)
Compiler failed on /Users/rodhcraft/Documents/LotusXD/Codes/para_llevar/lib/main.dart
Error launching application on iPhone XS Max.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this known issue https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22721
that was fixed upstream and should land in Flutter `master` channel soon (or has already landed)

Comment: I thought that was the problem, on first installation it was on Beta, so I changed to Master but the problem still there.

Comment: It's fixed in Dart. The last comment says it needs to roll to Flutter engine first, then it needs to roll into Flutter. This usually takes some time until Flutter is adapted to a new engine version the roll sticks to be available in `master`.